# How to install Python 3.5.x on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS without compiling anything

Tags: python, ubuntu

Simple question: How to install Python 3.5.x on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS without downloading source and compiling it (huge pain and slow).

I tried Deadsnakes PPA which is not working.  Isn't there an easy way to just install it?

Comment: This is probably better suited to askubuntu.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) for that purpose, which allows to easily install different Python versions, as well as libraries:

```
conda install python=3.5
```

Thus you can manage your Python packages.

Answer (score 4):

You can install Python3.5 from [deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) (It works):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt install python3.5
```

---

```
$ python3.5 
python 3.5.10 (default, Sep  8 2020, 22:44:55) 
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux
```

Comment: @AX Welcome, I have added this repository to my Ubuntu 18.04 and I have installed python3.5 before posting my answer. Maybe your probelem is defferent.

Comment: It also worked for me, this was starting from a VM which did not have any Python customizations before I did this. Could you elaborate in your comment exactly what error message you were seeing?